# Quais são as diferenças entre os comando sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Qual a diferença, quando devo utilizar os seguintes comandos sql e quais expressões que podem acompanhar esses comandos?

```
order by ,group by, join e union
```

Pra que serve e quando devo utilizar os comandos abaixo num select?

```
1) where nomedaColuna in

2) uso de uma subquery
```

Comment: Não tem como responder qual é mais rápido, você tem que testar com dados reais em situações específicas e verificar.

Comment: porque as pessoas mal veem a pergunta e negativam?.. já levei -4

Comment: É, não entendi o motivo neste caso, a pergunta não está na melhor forma mas não tem problemas sérios. De vez em quando alguém negativa sem saber porque e outros vão atrás porque alguém fez antes.

Comment: como devo prosseguir...perdi 8 pontos? não posso fechar essa pergunta pois já tem uma resposta e também não quero prejudicar quem me respondeu..

Comment: Eu acho que não há problemas em deixar. A resposta lhe ajudou? Parece ajudar outras pessoas. Quem sabe alguém retire o negativo. Quem sabe ganhe mais voto positivo.

Comment: @bigown me ajudou sim.. em partes eu fiz essa pergunta mais pra ajudar a pessoas que procuram tópicos relacionados à comandos sql do que propriamente à mim...

Comment: É uma dúvida extremamente básica, mas ninguém nasceu sabendo a resposta dela, portanto é pertinente. +1

Comment: @Bacco obrigado mesmo... como falei tem muitos fóruns de busca sobre comandos sql.. queria criar um nesse site pra discussão  e aprendizado.

Comment: @PedroRangel só tome um pouco de cuidado para não exagerar, não posso dizer porque negativaram mas sei que algumas pessoas não gostam de coisas muito básicas, que acha em qualquer lugar de forma muito fácil. Não estou dizendo que elas estão absolutamente certas, mas entendo que elas não queiram ver um monte de pergunta que existe em qualquer tutorial.

Comment: Pergunta canônica é sempre bom, pras dúvidas que são comuns a uma gama grande de usuários. A única recomendação é ler bem o **[ask]** e o **[FAQ da comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699/)** pra dar aquela "caprichada" na pergunta, sem "errar a mão". Vi pelas suas edições que você está começando a ser mais cuidadoso com a qualidade das postagens, isso é bom para todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe uma grande diferença entre os comandos que voce citou e não há como compará-los. Para te ajudar a entender cada um, vou explicar como funcionam.

Vou usar essas mesmas entidades com os seguintes dados em todos os exemplos:

```
                funcionarios
-----------------------------------------------
funcionarioId | nome             | departamento
-----------------------------------------------
  1           | Mauro Ramos      | Financeiro
  2           | Felipe Schimidt  | Compras
  3           | Luisa Maria      | Marketing
  4           | José Luiz        | Marketing
  5           | Valéria Viana    | Financeiro


              clientes
------------------------------------------
clienteId| nome             | grupo
------------------------------------------
  1      | Roberto Luiz     | VIP
  2      | Fabio Santos     | Normal
  3      | Mel Lisboa       | Normal
  4      | Ana Maria        | VIP
  5      | Lidiane Silva    | VIP

              vendas
--------------------------------------
 vendaId  |  clienteId  |   valor
--------------------------------------
    1     |     5       |  3.500,00
    2     |     4       |  1.500,00
    3     |     1       |  3.000,00
    4     |     3       |  2.200,00
    5     |     1       |  2.500,00
    6     |     5       |  4.000,00
    7     |     1       |    500,00
    8     |     3       |  1.000,00
```

Vamos lá

## Order By vs Group By

### Order By

O Order By é utilizado para ordenar o resultado de uma query, como por exemplo:

```
SELECT
  funcionarioId,
  nome,
  departamento
FROM
  funcionarios
ORDER BY
  departamento;
```

Essa consulta traria o seguinte resultado:

```
funcionarioId | nome             | departamento
------------------------------------------
  2           | Felipe Schimidt  | Compras
  5           | Valéria Viana    | Financeiro
  1           | Mauro Ramos      | Financeiro
  3           | Luisa Maria      | Marketing
  4           | José Luiz        | Marketing
```

Repare que a coluna departamento foi utilizada para ordenação, e que ficou em ordem alfabética.

A ordenação padrão é ASC (ascendente) mas podemos também utilizar a ordem inversa DESC (descendente)

```
SELECT
  funcionarioId,
  nome,
  departamento
FROM
  funcionarios
ORDER BY
  funcionarioId DESC;
```

E o resultado seria

```
funcionarioId | nome             | departamento
------------------------------------------
  5           | Valéria Viana    | Financeiro
  4           | José Luiz        | Marketing
  3           | Luisa Maria      | Marketing
  2           | Felipe Schimidt  | Compras
  1           | Mauro Ramos      | Financeiro
```

### Group By

A cláusula **GROUP BY** é utilizada para agrupar dados quando utilizamos expressões na consulta. Essas expressões podem ser, por exemplo `SUM, COUNT, AVG`. Por exempo

```
SELECT
  departamento,
  COUNT(funcionarioId) as membros
FROM
  funcionarios
GROUP BY
  departamento;
```

O resultado seria

```
departamento | membros
Financeiro   | 2
Compras      | 1
Marketing    | 2
```

E ainda pode ser utilizado em combinação com o **ORDER BY**

```
SELECT
  departamento,
  COUNT(pessoaId) as mebros
FROM
  pessoas
GROUP BY
  departamento
ORDER BY
  departamento;
```

Quer seria

```
departamento | membros
-----------------------
Compras      | 1
Financeiro   | 2
Marketing    | 2
```

## Join vs Union

### Join

Imagine se quiséssemos trazer uma listagem de todas as vendas com os nomes dos clientes, o nome está na tabela de clientes e tabela de vendas só conhece o id do cliente, para isso utilizamos o **JOIN**

O Join deve ser feito vinculando quais campos que identificam os registros entre as tabelas.

Existem alguns tipos de JOIN e você pode ver mais sobre eles [nessa excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448) do [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco)

```
SELECT
  V.vendaId,
  V.clienteId,
  C.nome AS nomeCliente,
  V.valor
FROM
  vendas V
  INNER JOIN cliente C on (V.clienteId = C.clienteId)
```

E o resultado seria

```
------------------------------------------------------
 vendaId  |  clienteId  |   nomeCliente   |   valor
------------------------------------------------------
    1     |     5       | Lidiane Silva   |  3.500,00
    2     |     4       | Ana Maria       |  1.500,00
    3     |     1       | Roberto Luiz    |  3.000,00
    4     |     3       | Mel Lisboa      |  2.200,00
    5     |     1       | Roberto Luiz    |  2.500,00
    6     |     5       | Lidiane Silva   |  4.000,00
    7     |     1       | Roberto Luiz    |    500,00
    8     |     3       | Mel Lisboa      |  1.000,00
```

### UNION

O **UNION** é utilizado quando se deja unir (como o próprio nome diz) o resultado de duas queries.

No nosso caso, se quiséssemos levantar em uma query, todas as pessoas (clientes e funcionarios) da base de dados.

Para se utilizar o UNION, as queries devem ter o mesmo número de colunas, e os tipos de dados das colunas utilizadas devem ser compatíveis.

Sendo assim, teríamos:

```
SELECT
  clienteId AS Id,
  nome,
  grupo as Agrupamento
FROM
  clientes
UNION
SELECT
  funcionarioId as Id,
  nome,
  departamento as Agrupamento
FROM
  funcionarios
```

Que retornaria o seguinte resultado:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Id       | nome             | Agrupamento
-----------------------------------------------
  1      | Mauro Ramos      | Financeiro
  2      | Felipe Schimidt  | Compras
  3      | Luisa Maria      | Marketing
  4      | José Luiz        | Marketing
  5      | Valéria Viana    | Financeiro
  1      | Roberto Luiz     | VIP
  2      | Fabio Santos     | Normal
  3      | Mel Lisboa       | Normal
  4      | Ana Maria        | VIP
  5      | Lidiane Silva    | VIP
```

> Tenho de parar para resolver um problema aqui, depois termino com os outros comandos

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta.. mesmo incompleta agradeço sua ajuda espero o termino de sua resposta^^

Comment: @PedroRangel agora falta somente o subselect e o operador IN

Comment: ok agradecido^^